# CreateTopicPolicy in Kafka not calling validate() on topic creation

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to create a custom topic policy for Kafka topics. I have found that the constructor and the `configure()` method are called when the broker is started.
But the `validate()` method is not called whenever a new topic is created through the **kafka-topics.sh** tool.

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.*;
import org.apache.kafka.server.policy.*;
import java.util.*;
public class policy implements  CreateTopicPolicy
{
        public policy()
        {
        System.out.println("came to policy constructor");
        }
        public void configure(Map<String,?> map){

        System.out.println("came to configure in policy");

        }
        public void close(){
        System.out.println("closing");
        }
        public void validate(RequestMetadata requestMetadata) throws PolicyViolationException
        {
System.out.println("Came to validate in policy");
                throw new PolicyViolationException("policy violated");
        }
}
```

Is there any configuration to be set apart from this?

```
create.topic.policy.class.name
```

In the broker logs, I can see the messages..

```
came to policy constructor

came to configure in policy
```

But not `Came to validate in policy` when creating a new topic.

**Update:** The below answer works for the kafka-topics.sh tool, but it doesn't work for automatically created topics.

Is there a way to enforce validation on automatically created topics?
(I currently have set to auto topic creation to false, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using the `kafka-topics.sh` tool with the `--zookeeper` flag. In that case, topic policies are not invoked.

Topic policies are only invoked when topics are created (or altered) via the Admin API.

Since Kafka 2.2.0, `kafka-topics.sh` can be used with the `--bootstrap-server` flag to invoke the Admin API instead of directly using Zookeeper.

Comment: Yes, the zookeeper flag did not invoke the validate(), but the `bootstrap-server` flag did. Thank you :)

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't apply to automatically created topics, though.